# How can I return a non-concrete value from a function that supports some API?

Tags: haskell

I'm building an API between two models. I don't care if it returns a [] or Seq or anything Foldable is fine. But if I try to do that, I get errors.

```
module Main where
import Prelude hiding (foldr)
import Data.Foldable
import Data.Sequence

data Struct = Struct

main = do
  print $ foldr (+) 0 $ list Struct
  print $ foldr (+) 0 $ listFree Struct


listFree :: Foldable f => a -> f Int
listFree s = singleton 10

class TestClass a where
  list :: Foldable f => a -> f Int

instance TestClass Struct where
  list s = singleton 10
```

Both the listFree and the list definitions give the same error:

```
TestFoldable.hs:19:12:
Could not deduce (f ~ [])
from the context (Foldable f)
  bound by the type signature for
             list :: Foldable f => Struct -> f Int
  at TestFoldable.hs:19:3-15
  `f' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for list :: Foldable f => Struct -> f Int
      at TestFoldable.hs:19:3
In the expression: [10]
In an equation for `list': list s = [10]
In the instance declaration for `TestClass Struct'
```

Why is that? And what is the "right" way to accomplish what I'm trying to do here?

What I'm trying to accomplish is to hide the implementation from the caller. The actual data structure might be a Seq, IntMap, or anything else and most likely is not a list.

I'm getting responses that say "just return a list". But that means conversion, doesn't it? What if it's a 1,000,000 element structure? Converting it to an intermediate data structure just because of limitations of the API seems a poor solution.

And this is a general problem. How does one have a return value that conforms to some API? To hide the concrete implementation so the implementer is free to choose whatever structure is best for them and can change it without having to change the users of the API.

Another way of putting it is: how can I return an interface instead of a concrete type?

**Closing Note:**

The Haskell community on StackOverflow is (SuperlativeCompliment c => forall c. c)

Existential quantification seems like the general solution to this situation.

Another possibility to consider, which is not a general solution but might have worked for this specific case, that might avoid the extra wrapper value required by existential solution is to return a closure of the fold for the client:

```
list :: a -> ((Int -> b -> b) -> b -> b)
list = \f a0 -> foldr f a0 (singleton 10)
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the `s` in `listFree`?

Comment: Nothing, sorry, the `s` is noise in the example. I created the example from real code and that was left in.

Comment: I've upvoted this most recent question because it's now a very good question, and one that can be answered reasonably. New answer incoming.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your edit. In your example you returned [10], which is a list. Nobody said that you should just return a list - you already are returning a list. What I said was that you should change your return type to match what you're actually returning (i.e. say you're returning a list, which you are anyway). I don't see what would need to be converted in this scenario. Clearly [10] does not need to be converted to a list as it already is a list.

Comment: Your edit kind of makes it sound as if you want your return type to depends on your argument type (i.e. return the same type of collection that you get as an argument). If that's what you want, you can do that (e.g. something like `foo :: Functor f => f X -> f Y` would be easy to write, though if all you know about your argument is that it is foldable, that's not enough), but your example code really does not make that clear.

Comment: Ah, is that the confusion? I'll change my code to use a Seq instead to make it clear that I don't have a list.

Comment: @taotree: But now you can just change the return type to `Seq` and everythings fine. Having a polymorphic return type only makes sense if the function may return different types in different situations (which either means depending on the type of the argument or depending on the type the user wants). The way you defined it, it will always return the same type, so the type can't be polymorphic.

Comment: My question is how do I follow standard good principles of API writing. In other languages, this would be the principle of prefer interfaces instead of classes in your API. If the callee decides later that it's more efficient for its algorithm to use an IntMap, or Tree, or whatever instead of a Seq, it can do so without having to change all the callers (which could be a very large ripple effect). Isolating changes is critical to managing large software development.

Comment: Unlike OO languages, you cannot write "container oblivious" code in Haskell. The preferred solution is to return what structure is most natural internally for your library. Callers can then decide whether to change it to another representation or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

sepp2k already provided a good answer, but allow me to take a similar but slightly different angle. What you have done is provide result-type polymorphism. You wrote:

```
listFree :: Foldable f => a -> f Int
```

What this does is promise that you can produce *any* foldable that the user may need. You, of course, could never keep this promise because `Foldable` doesn't provide any constructor-like functions.

So what you're trying to do deals with generics. You want to make a weak promise: the function `listFree` will produce *some* `Foldable`, but in the future, it may change. You might implement it with a regular list today, but later, you might re-implement it with something else. And you want this implementation detail to be just that: an implementation detail. You want the *contract* for that function (the type signature) to remain the same.

Sounds like a job for yet another weird and confusing Haskell extension! Existential Quantification!

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

import Prelude hiding (foldr, foldl, foldr1, foldl1)
import Data.Foldable

data SomeFoldable a = forall f. Foldable f => F (f a)

foo :: SomeFoldable Int
foo = F [1,2,3]
```

Here I've provide a value `foo`, but it has the type `SomeFoldable Int`. I'm not telling you *which* `Foldable` it is, simply that it is *some* foldable. `SomeFoldable` can easily be made an instance of `Foldable`, for convenience.

```
instance Foldable SomeFoldable where
  fold (F xs) = fold xs
  foldMap f (F xs) = foldMap f xs
  foldr step z (F xs) = foldr step z xs
  foldl step z (F xs) = foldl step z xs
  foldr1 step (F xs) = foldr1 step xs
  foldl1 step (F xs) = foldl1 step xs
```

Now we can do `Foldable` things with `foo`, for example:

```
> Data.Foldable.sum foo
6
```

But we can't do anything with it besides what `Foldable` exposes:

```
> print foo
No instance for (Show (SomeFoldable Int)) blah blah blah
```

It's easy to adapt your code to work as desired:

```
data Struct = Struct

main = do
  print $ foldr (+) 0 $ list Struct
  print $ foldr (+) 0 $ listFree Struct


listFree :: a -> SomeFoldable Int
listFree s = F [10]

class TestClass a where
  list :: a -> SomeFoldable Int

instance TestClass Struct where
  list s = F [10]
```

But remember, Existential Quantification has its drawbacks. There is no way to unwrap `SomeFoldable` to get the concrete `Foldable` underneath. The reason for this is the same reason that your function signature was wrong at the beginning: it promises result-type polymorphism: a promise it cannot keep.

```
unwrap :: Foldable f => SomeFoldable a -> f a   -- impossible!
unwrap (F xs) = xs    -- Nope. Keep dreaming. This won't work.
```

Comment: I just noticed Tarrach's answer, which is almost identical. GADTs subsume Existential Quantification. :)

Comment: "There is no way to unwrap SomeFoldable..."  That's not a drawback, that's intentional.

Comment: Well, an intentional drawback, then. :) "Restriction" would be a better word I suppose.

Comment: +1. It might be much like my answer technically, GADT and Existentials do pretty much the same job here. However, I think this answer is better elaborated.

Answer (score 8):

> Why is that?

The type `Foldable f => a -> f Int` does *not* mean that the function might return any foldable it wants. It means that the function will return whichever type the user wants. I.e. if the user uses the function in a context where a list is required that should work and if he uses it in a context where a Seq is required that should also work. Since this is clearly not the case with your definition, it doesn't match its type.

> And what is the "right" way to accomplish what I'm trying to do here?

The easiest way would be to just make your function return a list.

However if you do need to hide the fact that you're using lists from your users, the easiest way would be to create a wrapper type around the list and not export that type's constructor. I.e. something like:

```
module Bla (ListResult(), list) where
data ListResult a = ListResult [a]

instance Foldable (ListResult a) where
    foldr op s (ListResult xs) = foldr op s xs

list s = ListResult [10]
```

Now if the user imports your module, it can fold over a ListResult because it's foldable, but it can't unpack it to get at the list because the constructor is not exported. So if you later change `ListResult`'s definition to `data ListResult a = ListResult (Seq a)` and `list` to also use a `Seq` instead of a list, that change will be completely invisible to the user.

Comment: I don't want to return a list because what if the function implementer already has a Seq or IntMap or something else? I don't want to have to convert it to a list just to implement this function--there's no need. The caller just needs to fold on the result, so the only contract we need in this function is that the caller can fold the result.

Comment: @taotree I'm a bit confused. If the caller just needs to fold on the result, why does it matter what other stuff he has lying around? You can fold on a list whether you have another value that's a `Seq` or not.

Comment: I think I'm really not explaining my question well and I'm sorry. I have added more to the question. The thing about list is if I have a Seq, why waste the processing and memory of converting it to a list when the caller should be able to use the existing structure directly?

Comment: Great answer. Explains the why very well. I think the existential approach given in other answers is the more appropriate general solution.

Answer (score 5):

The `Foldable` class only provides methods for destructing instances of `Foldable`, and none for constructing instances. The complete list of class methods is reproduced below:

```
class Foldable t where
    fold :: Monoid m => t m -> m
    foldMap :: Monoid m => (a -> m) -> t a -> m
    foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
    foldl :: (a -> b -> a) -> a -> t b -> a
    foldr1 :: (a -> a -> a) -> t a -> a
    foldl1 :: (a -> a -> a) -> t a -> a
```

You can see that the return type of these methods never has a "t foo" type. So you cannot construct a value that is polymorphic in which `Foldable` instance you choose.

However, there *are* classes over type constructors for which the constructor appears in the return type of at least one method. For instance, there is

```
class Pointed p where
    point :: a -> p a
```

provided by the [pointed](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pointed/2.0.3/doc/html/Data-Pointed.html) package. There is also the `Monoid` class provided by `base`:

```
class Monoid m where
    mempty :: m
    mappend :: m -> m -> m
    mconcat :: [m] -> m
```

You could combine these two classes like so:

```
points :: (Pointed p, Monoid (p a)) => [a] -> p a
points = mconcat . map point
```

For example, in ghci:

```
> points [7,3,8] :: Set Int
fromList [3,7,8]
> points [7,3,8] :: First Int
First { getFirst = Just 7 }
> points [7,3,8] :: Last Int
Last { getLast = Just 8 }
> points [7,3,8] :: [Int]
[7,3,8]
> points [7,3,8] :: Seq Int
fromList [7,3,8]
```

etc.

Comment: This is interesting, but I don't even know how it applies to what I'm trying to do. I think you're answering a different question because of my ignorance in describing my question.

Comment: @taotree I see your edited question says, "All I want is a function to be able to return something that the caller can fold on.". So just return a list.

Answer (score 0):

The updated question has a very different answer. (Since my other answer is a good one, but answering a *different question*, I'm going to leave it.)

Create an [abstract data type](http://haskell.org/haskellwiki/Abstract_data_type). The short of it is to define a new type in your module

```
newtype Struct a = Struct [a]
```

where here I've assumed for now that `[a]` is the concrete implementation that you want to hide. Then, you add a `Foldable` instance.

```
deriving instance Foldable Struct
-- could do this on the newtype definition line above,
-- but it doesn't fit with the flow of the answer
```

At the module boundary, you hide the actual implementation by exporting the `Struct` type, but not the `Struct` constructor. The only thing your callers will be able to do with a `Struct a` is call `Foldable` methods on it.

Comment: Wrong kind for the instance, `newtype Struct a = Struct [a]` would be it.

Comment: Thanks! I think the existential solution is more precisely what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As sepp2k said in his answer,
the problem is that we must have a monomorph return type.
Like a list in his answer.

However, we can still return a wrappertype that has a named type,
`FoldableContainer`, yet it is `Foldable`.
To achieve this we need GADTts.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
module Main where
import Prelude hiding (foldr)
import Data.Foldable

data Struct = Struct

data FoldableContainer a where
  F :: Foldable f => f a -> FoldableContainer a

instance Foldable FoldableContainer where
  foldMap g (F f) = foldMap g f

main = do
  print $ foldr (+) 0 $ list Struct
  print $ foldr (+) 0 $ listFree Struct


listFree :: a -> FoldableContainer Int
listFree s = F [10]

class TestClass a where
  list :: a -> FoldableContainer Int

instance TestClass Struct where
  list s = F [10]
```

Note however that while this works it might as some say indeed be better
to just return a list. Why? First of all we create no extra type,
and second of all, each constructed `F` will need to carry alongside
the `Foldable` dictionary since it isn't known at compile time.
I don't know how much performence penalty this is but it must not be forgotten.
On the other hand we don't need lists as intermedite types anymore,
that is using `sum` on `Set Int` need not first be converted to a `[Int]`.

Comment: Can you expand a bit on what this GADT offers over sepp2k's answer?

Comment: @DanielWagner: I included a little discussion in the end of my answer. Basically it is performance gain/lose. Note also that the solution I posted is general. All `Foldable` can be made `[]` and maintain `Foldable`-ness. This does not hold for most type classes. GADT being more general for this specific problem indicates that lists are more simple to use. But one should be aware of this general solution when encountering similar problems.

Comment: You mention performance, is the GADT solution faster/slower than the existential solution? Also, I don't understand "All `Foldable` can be made `[]` and maintain `Foldable`-ness"

Comment: @taotree regarding GADT vs existentials, I just asked on #haskell, and edwardk says that in ghc they are implemented with the same stuff, but in theory existentials could be lighter weight.

Comment: Compared to existentials they should be the same. Both solutions introduce *constructors that carries a dictionary*, that introduces overhead. However they also both have the same bonus over list-approach, namely *a returned value (be it a `Set`, `[]`, or `Seq`) can directly get folded on*, no convert-to-list overhead. (Also Dan is right, existentials might be lighter, but are nevertheless more elegant)